# Meaning of "missile"

Tags: meaning

What's a missile in this case?

> Would you rather a cop grab a quick nap while not on a call if they're exhausted or drive around a two ton missile with a gun on their hip while half asleep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*A two ton missile* is presumably a jokey way of describing the kind of vehicle that some police officers use.

Comment: Yep - definitely refers to the large chunk of metal called a police cruiser. +1

Comment: Many of the cyclists I know refer to them as "two-ton killing machines."

Comment: Also cops can legally exceed the speed limit if needed, and high speed is a prominent attribute of missiles.